# Ammeter show half of the real current draw

Tags: meter, power-meter

I have a couple of ammeters from China, they have 2 connectors:

Con 1: Yellow voltage sense, Black and Red to power the ammeter.

Con 2: Thick Red and black for current sense.

[image]

They are designed to run with two different voltage sources but i'm connecting everything from same power supply, the problem is the current is being cut at half, for example i set my load to 2A, the bench power supply shows 2A draw, but the ammeter show just 1A and the voltage is correct (24V in this case)
I also have tried other unit but both does the same thing. They have U and V pot to ajust the values but that doesn't help since it's already calibrated and at max position.

Suggested connections:

[image]

I connect like that but the power meter will connect to the battery, so just one power source and one load, so red and yellow are connected together.

My connection:
[image]

The fact this is made with two power sources causing this problem?

[image]

Comment: Possibly the reason the power supply is showing more current is that the meter is drawing some. It seems odd that it would draw 1A, but it will draw some current. Also, consider calibrating it with a cheap multimeter

Comment: "I have a couple of ammeters from China" there is your problem

Comment: @C_Elegans Can't be, my bench power supply is accurate and both ps and electronic load shows 2A.

Comment: @PlasmaHH that would be so bad since i buy 10 units :( in fact they were so cheap but i will try two power sources and test if ammeter current stay the same or change

Comment: What shunt value are they made for, probably you just used the wrong shunt value.

Comment: They come with shunt already, up to 10A
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Mini-Digital-Voltmeter-Ammeter-DC-100V-10A-Panel-Amp-Volt-Current-Meter-Tester-0-28-Blue/32824062417.html

Comment: This sure sounds like a mismatch of firmware / shunt / configuration jumper, in a design supporting multiple ranges.  To verify you could try a test current of a substantially different magnitude and see if that is also off by a factor of two.  Perhaps the seller will send you new ones, or perhaps you can replace the shunt.  Or if you're in for an adventure, write a new firmware - often this kind of thing uses some version of the STM8 MCU.

Comment: Your circuit looks okay to me, maybe they are defective (wrong internal shunt) though it's a mystery how they would have have calibrated them so far off the nominal (maybe they just cranked it to max and shipped it). Usually the shunt is just a U-shaped piece of alloy wire near the current connector.

Comment: There are no visible jumper label indicator but there are a few resistors, i will try contact the seller and ask. So strange the product have many good feedback at page. I can post a image of the board but they are generic, the shunt is U shape

Comment: I have uploaded a board image

Comment: connecting the thin black wire to the wrong thick wire will cause the meter to read low. - perhaps re-test using a battery to power the meter or leave the thin black unconnected.

Comment: what readings do you get with the thick red wire disconnected (should be close to 0.0A on all three displays)

Comment: "i was using it with the TS100 iron" beware likely pulsed loads, which may interact poorly with the meter sampling/averaging code

Comment: @Chris Stratton TS100 only pulse load when mantain the same temperature, while cold boot is constant load 2.5A +/- at 24V util reach the desired temperature. But as i said i also test with Electronic Constant Load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These meters put the current measuring shunt in the negative supply line.
care must be taken to avoid all ground loops.

Also note they are average reading, not RMS, so should only be used with reasonably stable sources.

Also the thin black wire terminal connects internally to one end of the current shunt (and from the photos it appears most-likely to connect to the red end)  if you connect it to the wrong end it will parallel the shunt causing low current readings.

I would re-test with an passive load like an automotive brake lamp to be sure that the load negative terminal is isolated from the supply negative.

The thin black wire should only be used if you're using an isolated supply to run the instrument, if you're connecting thin red to thin yellow to power the meter from the voltmeter input, or any other supply not isolated from the current being measured) leave the thin black unconnected: cut it off, remove it from the plug, or insulate it.

Comment: That did the trick! Problem was the thin black wire i have connected. Once i disconnect the measurement goes well! Not perfect accurate, but very near real value, it fit my needs. Tested with range of 1A to 5A with same constant readings. Thank you

Comment: you may find that the current use to power the display is being added to the reading :( the only cure is an isolated supply.

Comment: The total current draw inc. ammeter does not matter, only the connected load, so it meet my requirements :) Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

P.S. Below assumes you have the circuit connected correctly as you say, and your electronic load is not doing anything strange. I suggest you replace the electronic load with a resistor just as a quick check to make sure that the electronic load does not have a sneak path to ground that is shunting the shunt. 
I don't think that could lead to both the power supply and electronic load agreeing though.

---

Looking at one of these that I have there is a shunt, maybe 10m\$\Omega\$, I didn't try to measure it very accurately.

There is a POS LM358 preamp on the shunt to get it up to the voltage where the ADC in the 8S003F3P6 uC can read it.

The circuit looks something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV2vMs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Yes, pins 1..4 of the chip are connected together. Resistor numbers are not on the unit, just for reference here.

Here R7 provides a slight offset (4mV) to overcome the op-amp offset. They may have fiddled the firmware to display exactly zero if the number is close to zero and/or subtracted a bit digitally in the firmware. If you get that wrong in fiddling with it, it may not "idle" with zero showing or it may require a bit of current before it budges from zero.

The nominal gain is 1 + 185/8.2 = 23.6, so 100mV would give 2.36V.

If they stuffed the wrong part for R5 (too high)  or R6 (too low) the reading could be made half.

---

Edit: From your photo, the gain of your preamp is 1 + (47K+5K)K/2.2K = 24.6, assuming a 10K pot, so **very** close to mine. Which, of course, points to an incorrect shunt.

The shunt wire in mine is about 1.45mm diameter. Of course there's no guarantee they are made of the same resistivity material.

Comment: My shunt is 0.20ohm, i have tried other units and the best current offset is +0.3A, so 1A = 1.3A and 2A = 2.6A...
I think i will use this only for voltmeter and ignore the current. I spot that stange current draw because i was using it with the TS100 iron, and current was incorrect showing 1.23A instead of 2.5A while heating

Comment: @TiagoConceição You could change the 47K (473) beside the pot to 100K and recalibrate.

Comment: @TiagoConceição, "My shunt is 0.20ohm" -  it looks highly unlikely for a wire that thick. If you can measure the shunt with that accuracy, just make another shunt with twice value. I  have tried two similar modules, and they did work just fine, which was amazing.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany i can test that latter, it can work but test and fix 10 modules will be a pain, the pot range is just to low, they should have allowed a better offset range

Comment: @Ali Chen I measure the shunt on board, the correct measurement must be done outside board, that maybe give the wrong value, my Multimeter is .4 digit precision

Comment: @TiagoConceição, I am still not convinced with your measurement technique. But what you can do is to trim your existing shunt with a mechanical Dremel tool, until it gives you right readings. You will need to shave the wire by half.